# Is it ok to call wait_event inside a semaphore?

Tags: c, concurrency, linux-kernel, wait, semaphore

Are there any risks/dangers/complications if I did something like

```
up(&sem);
wait_event_interruptible(....);
down(&sem);
```

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is it ok? Provisionally, yes.  Are there risks? Yes: depending on the condition you are waiting for and what has to happen in order for it to become true, you can produce deadlock by going into an indefinite wait while holding a resource that other threads must acquire in order to make progress.

Comment: Note, however, that your particular example code appears to *release* a resource before waiting, not acquire it.  In that sense, it is not well characterized as a demonstration of waiting "inside" a semaphore.

Comment: Did you reverse `up` and `down`? If you're using a semaphore as a mutex, the wait is *outside* (not inside) of the protected area in the code you depicted.